# Escalation Engineer vs Software Developer

Tags: escalation

I'm currently considering a position as a escalation engineer in one of the big sofware companies (Microsoft, Apple, Google, etc), in which I'd ultimately like to work on product development, but I'm afraid going straight for that kind of a job would be quite challenging.

So I wonder what people's thoughts are about this kind of move? I currently work as a software developer, and am thinking about attempting this sort of move: going in as an escalation engineer, to prove myself, and maybe be able to then move to product development.

Also, what are people's thoughts on Escalation Engineer vs regular Software Engineer?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this should be on SO

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling this might not be the right place. But upon googling for stackoverflow careers forums, i came up empty. Does anyone know where I should direct this question? Thanks